# Passing two models to controller second model is null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

am trying to pass two models to a controller but the second model is null. where could be going wrong
**blade view**

```
{!! link_to_route('schools.school-classes.edit', 'Edit', array($school->id, $class->id), array('class'=>'label label-info')) !!}
```

web.php code is

```
Route::bind('school-classes', function ($value, $route){
return \App\SchoolClass::whereId($value)->first();
}); 
Route::bind('schools', function ($value, $route){
return \App\School::whereId($value)->first();
});
Route::resource('schools', 'SchoolsController');
Route::resource('schools.school-classes', 'SchoolClassesController');
```

when i run php artisan route:list i get

```
 GET|HEAD  | schools/{school}/school-classes/{school_class}/edit | schools.school-classes.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\SchoolClassesController@edit       | web
```

in my controller

```
public function edit(School $school, SchoolClass $class){
    var_dump($class);
}
```

$class is null. where could I be going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes being generated contains underscore (`_`) instead of dash (`-`). You need to set your bindings accordingly:

```
// use 'school_class' instead of 'school_classes'
Route::bind('school_class', function ($value, $route){
    return \App\SchoolClass::whereId($value)->first();
});
```